# How to prove $(1-2x)^2=1/3+4/\pi^2\sum_1^\infty \cos(2n x \pi)/n^2$ for $x \in [0,1)$?

Tags: analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

I tried to prove that
$$(1-2x)^2=1/3+4/\pi^2\sum_1^\infty \cos(2n x \pi)/n^2$$ for $x \in [0,1)$ with Fourier analysis, but I just found a Fourier series which defines the function. I also found the fourier series of $\cos(2n x \pi)$.

I don't think these results are helpful.

Any suggestions on how to prove this equation?

Comment: I don't know how to do it...

Comment: Do you know about cosine Fourier series?

Comment: Briefly (......)

Comment: @tomerg: The most important point is to put the mathematical equation in dollar signs,'$'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint/Problems**

(*Changed since the previous was wrong -- the function is not even in it self..*)

1. Note first that $x\mapsto e(x)=(1-2x)^2$ is even on $[0,1]$ in the sense $e(x)= e(1-x)$ (either visualise it or by computation $(1-2(1-x))^2 = (1-2+2x)^2 = (-1+2x)^2)$).
2. Now, let us look at the function $s$ on $I=[-1,1]$, which is the *even extension* of the function $x\mapsto (1-2x)^2$ on $[0,1]$ (so the graph looks a bit like $\omega$).
3. Note that the sine Fourier coefficients are 0, while the cosine Fourier coefficients are given by $$a_n = 2\int_0^1s(x)\cos(n\pi x)dx.$$
4. Next $a_n=0$ for odd $n$, this follows from 1 (try to see why without a calculation) or a simple calculation, and for even $n\ne0$ we have 
   $$a_n= \frac{16}{n^2\pi^2}$$
   while $a_0=2/3$.
5. Why is $s$ equal to the Fourier series on $[-1,1]$?
6. What is $s$ equal to in $[0,1]$?

---

*Last edit*

For even $n$ we have $n=2k$ for some $k$ and that $a_0$ should be divided by 2 in the expansion.

Comment: I found the fourier series with respect to [-1,1] by using step 1 but it does not fit the series in the question...

Comment: You are right, I will add more appropriate hints!

Comment: This is not quite right, since $s(-x)=(1+2x)^2 \neq s(x)$...

Comment: @HansLundmark Yes, I changed it accordingly.. I did not visualise the function correctly...

Comment: what's an even extension? can you write function s?

Comment: @tomerg A function $f$ defined on $[0,1]$ can be extended to an even function $F$ on $[-1,1]$ by letting $F(x)=f(x)$ for $0\le x\le1$ and $F(x)=f(-x)$ for $-1\le x\le0$ (note that for such an $x$ we have $0\le-x\le1$, so that $f(-x)$ has a meaning). Hence in our case (even though we do not need it) $F(x) = (1-2(-x))^2=(1+2x)^2$ for a negative $x\ge-1$.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the equivalent problem using $y=x-\frac12$ on the interval $[-\frac12,\frac12]$: Prove that
$$
4y^2=\frac13+\frac{4}{\pi^2}\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^n\frac{\cos(2\pi ny)}{n^2}\tag{1}
$$
Since $\pi\csc(\pi z)$ has residue $(-1)^n$ at each integer, let's consider $f_y(z)=\pi\csc(\pi z)\frac{\cos(2\pi zy)}{z^2}$.

Let $\gamma_N$ be the rectangular path
$$
(N{+}\!\tfrac12)-iN\to(N{+}\!\tfrac12)+iN\to-(N{+}\!\tfrac12)+iN\to-(N{+}\!\tfrac12)-iN\to(N{+}\!\tfrac12)-iN
$$
It is not hard to see that for $|y|<\frac12$,
$$
\lim_{N\to\infty}\;\;\oint_{\gamma_N}f_y(z)\;\mathrm{d}z=0\tag{2}
$$
Equation $(2)$ relates the residue of $f_y$ at $0$ with the sum in $(1)$:
$$
\operatorname{Res}(f_y,0)+ 2\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^n\frac{\cos(2n\pi y)}{n^2}=0\tag{3}
$$
Let's look at the Laurent series for $f_y$:
$$
\begin{align}
\pi\csc(\pi z)\frac{\cos(2\pi zy)}{z^2}
&=\left(\frac1z+\frac{\pi^2}{6}z+\dots\right)\left(\frac{1}{z^2}-2\pi^2y^2+\dots\right)\\
&=\frac{1}{z^3}+\left(\frac{\pi^2}{6}-2\pi^2y^2\right)\frac{1}{z}+\dots\tag{4}
\end{align}
$$
Equation $(4)$ says that $\operatorname{Res}(f_y,0)=\frac{\pi^2}{6}-2\pi^2y^2$. Combining this with $(3)$ yields
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^n\frac{\cos(2n\pi y)}{n^2}=\pi^2\left(y^2-\frac{1}{12}\right)\tag{5}
$$
which immediately verfies $(1)$.

Answer (score 1):

The series on the right hand has terms of the form $a_n\cos(2\pi n x)$ with $a_n\ne0$ for all $n$. This indicates a fundamental period of length $L=1$. When the sum of such a series is claimed to be equal to the function $f\!: x\mapsto (1-2x)^2$ on the interval $[0,1]$ then it has to be the Fourier series of the function $\tilde f$ obtained from $f$ by periodic extension with period $1$. As $\tilde f$ is even (check it!) its Fourier series contains only $\cos$-terms $a_n\cos(2\pi n x)$ to begin with. The $a_n$ are given by the formula
$$ a_n={2\over L}\int_0^L(1-2x)^2\ \cos(2\pi n x)\ dx = 2\int_0^1(1-2x)^2\ \cos(2\pi n x)\ dx\ .$$
For $n\geq 1$ the integral can be evaluated by partial integration (2 times); the case $n=0$ is immediate. Doing the calculations you will see that you get exactly the $a_n$ in the title.

So we know now that the formal Fourier series of $\tilde f$ is actually the series in the title. In order to finish the case we have to invoke a fundamental theorem about such series: When $\tilde f$ is an $L$-periodic continuous function of bounded variation per period then its formal Fourier series converges uniformly on ${\mathbb R}$ to $\tilde f(x)$. Since the assumptions of the theorem are obviously satisfied in our case, the claim follows.

Comment: My problem is verifying that the fourier series are what written in the title.